# How to start for a slam system

Tags: turtlebot, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ROS Indigo with ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to make a slam system on a simulated environment. Now, my question is How should I get started with a robot simulator? I have seen tutorials on turtlebot, but they I think are for real hardware, but I needed a simulated turtlebot. where could I find tutorials on that?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262643/how-to-start-for-a-slam-system/) by [Isam Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/25753/isam-abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
you can use [gazebo simulator](http://gazebosim.org/)  to simulate your robot and sensor then subscribe sensors output in Ros
for turtlebot you can use [turtlebot_gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_gazebo)

you can use hector slam with hokuyo laser scanner or lsd_slam with mono camera and rtab-map with kinect and ....

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2017-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0